# Swift: sum of two max integers

Tags: integer, swift

I'm playing with swift's integers. Got a strange one:

```
let uIntMax8 = UInt8.max
let uIntMax16 = UInt16.max
let sumInt32: Int32 = Int32(uIntMax16 + UInt16(uIntMax8))
sumInt32
```

swift can't calculate the `sum` for me.
Why is that?

Comment: try this: `let sumInt32: Int32 = Int32(Int32(uIntMax16) + Int32(uIntMax8))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `uIntMax16 + UInt16(uIntMax8)` can't fit into 16 bits. Adding **anything** to `UInt16.max` will exceed 16 bits, pretty much by definition.  You need to convert both summands to `UInt32` prior to doing the addition.

Comment: To expand on @pjs answer, by default all math operations in swift are performed with overflow and bounds checking, so you get an exception trying to add anything to UInt16.max.

Comment: @purrrminator I'm not sure what you're saying since it's detecting the overflow in both cases.

Comment: pjs's answer is correct but I'd like to add that you can still force overflow addition by using the `&+` operator: `let sumInt32: Int32 = Int32(uIntMax16 &+ uIntMax16)`

Answer (score 0):

```
let uIntMax8 = Int32(UInt8.max)
let uIntMax16 = Int32(UInt16.max)
let sumInt32: Int32 = uIntMax16 + uIntMax8
sumInt32
```